# Why do I get different values from size?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, apparently, I get different values for width and height when I use size in these two ways:

```
% way 1
[height, width] = size(myLoadedImage);

% way 2
height = size(myLoadedImage, 1);
width = size(myLoadedImage, 2)
```

Why are these two ways different?

Comment: What is the result of `size(myLoadedImage)` by itself on the command line? Maybe it is a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: `512 143 3`. Thanks, what happens if we have a 3D array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [complete help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) for the `size` function. Specifically it says

```
[d1,d2,d3,...,dn] = size(X), for n > 1, returns the sizes of the dimensions of 
the array X in the variables d1,d2,d3,...,dn, provided the number of output
arguments n equals ndims(X).

If n does not equal ndims(X), the following exceptions hold:

n < ndims(X)   di equals the size of the ith dimension of X for 0<i<n, but dn 
               equals the product of the sizes of the remaining dimensions of X, 
               that is, dimensions n through ndims(X).
```

As shown by your comment, your image is a 3-dimensional array. So as per the manual, if you are asking for only 2 out of the 3 sizes with `[h,w] = size(...)`, the parameter `w` will contain the product of the 2nd and 3rd dimension. When doing `h = size(..., 1)` and `w = size(..., 2)`, you get the exact values of the first and second dimensions.

Simulating your case:

```
>> im = randn(512, 143, 3);
>> h = size(im, 1)
h = 512
>> w = size(im, 2)
w = 143
>> [h, w] = size(im)
h = 512
w = 429
```

Note that in the last case `w = 143 * 3 = 429`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@BasSwinckels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18936900/97160) explanation, you can write:

```
[h,w,~] = size(img);
```

This will work for any number of dimensions (grayscale image, RGB image, or higher dimension arrays).